# Microsoft graph gives an error of 403 Forbidden when subscribing to notifications API for the 12th group subscription

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I am using an Azure function for subscribing to Microsoft Graph notifications API for group updates. I need to subscribe to around 100 groups belonging to the same tenant, using one common notificationUrl.

According to online documentations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notifications), we have the limitations as below.

**Certain limits apply to Azure AD based resources (users, groups) and may generate errors when exceeded:**

**Per app: 50,000 total subscriptions**

**Per tenant: 35 total subscriptions across all apps**

**Per app and tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions**

**Azure AD B2C tenants are not supported.**

**Notification for user entities are not supported for personal Microsoft accounts.**

I have created a function and was able to create 11 active subscriptions and receive notifications:

•   1 subscription to all groups on a tenant, created 2 days back.

•   10 subscriptions which are to specific groups and on the same tenant, today.

On trying to create the 12th subscription to another group in the same tenant, i am getting a 403 Forbidden response from Graph when sending create subscription request. I have deleted some active subscriptions and tried to create, and it again fails to create the 12th active subscription.

Any suggestion/answers to the following would be of great help:

1. The numbers mentioned in above limitations are not matching to our scenario where we can have only 11 active subscriptions. Is there any additional scenario/case that exists which is stopping from creating further subscriptions to same notificationUrl?
2. Since i tried to create 10 subscriptions continuously within an hour’s time, is there any rule as to only a limited number of subscriptions can be created in a specific interval of time to the same notificationUrl? 
   And if this case is true, we were able to delete and create exactly same number of active subscriptions.
3. Bit of explanation of the above limitations would be useful so that the impact of these limitations is more clear to me in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. Short term, we will fix the limit enforcement to be precise, so you won't see the confusing behavior with the system allowing you to create slightly more subscriptions than the limit allows.
2. Long term, we plan to make improvements to the system to allow us to have much higher subscription limits. We cannot provide an ETA at this time.
3. We also plan to add filtering capability to notifications, so you could in the future subscribe to "resource": "groups?$filter=
4. In the meantime, for scenarios like yours we recommend you subscribe to notifications on all groups ("resource": "groups") and quickly drop irrelevant changes. That is the only practical approach available.